# RStudio: Can't use file.remove() on recently scraped PDF

Tags: r

I'm using RStudio to download PDFs from a Google Drive folder into a folder on my PC, rename the PDFs, scrape them into CSVs, combine the CSVs into a *"combined_data.csv"*, and then move all files except *"combined_data.csv"* into another local folder -- and delete them from the first folder on my PC.

This is all working, except when I attempt to use `file.remove()` on the files in the original folder. I get a warning message "Permission Denied" on one of my PDFs. If I try to delete it by right clicking in the folder, it states

> "The action can't be completed because the file is open in RStudio R
> Session."

Below is the script I'm using:

```
AllFiles <- list.files("starting_folder_path") %>%
  stringr::str_subset(., "combined_data", negate = TRUE)

file.copy(from = AllFiles,
          to   = "target_folder_path")

file.remove(AllFiles)
```

I've found a couple suggestions on stackoverflow -- using `unlink()` and `closeAllConnections()` before using `file.remove()`  -- but neither has worked. I've also tried running Rstudio as an administrator and that did not work. It works if I close Rstudio, or use `.rs.restartR()`, before running `file.remove()` -- but then I have to run the rest of my script, so its not optimal.

Any solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Download to your temp folder instead

Comment: If you wait a few seconds after the `file.copy()`, does it make any difference?  A common problem on Windows is that some antivirus program opens a new file to check it and holds it open for a while.  Sometimes adding delays to the script is the only thing you can do other than disabling the antivirus program, which could be risky.